# Change deployment reason for Azure WebServices

Tags: web-services, azure, continuous-integration

I have been working on moving our continuous integration(CI) to Azure using Azure's built in CI. After each build, it shows the last commit message as the deployment reason. I would like to put the current version of my App in there.

Does anybody know if there is a way I can override, or extend the information shown in the Deployment details view after a build for Azure WebServices.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anywhere to add this, so I guess [UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com/for/visual-studio-online/) is the best way to get their attention. I'd certainly vote it up.